# Can't rewrite product variation URL using add_rewrite_rule in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I have an issue, I need to rewrite the variation slug for products in WooCommerce.
For example, I have this URL:

```
http://localhost:8888/wordpress/product/wordpress-pennant/?attribute_pa_color=blue
```

What I need is this one:

```
http://localhost:8888/wordpress/product/wordpress-pennant/blue
```

I tried this code, but it doesn't work:

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_rewrite_rules' );
function add_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^product/([^/]*)?',
        'index.php?product=$matches[1]&attribute_pa_color=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
    add_rewrite_tag('%attribute_pa_color%', '([^&]+)');
}
```

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong, I also made flush for permalinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out that I have mistakes in my code, so finally it should be like this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_rewrite_rules' );
function add_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^product/(.+?)/(.+?)/?$', 'index.php?product=$matches[1]&attribute_pa_color=$matches[2]', 'top');
    add_rewrite_tag('%attribute_pa_color%', '([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)');
}
```

Comment: Remember to flush your permalinks on each time you change the code. Otherwise it won't work.